# node js TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined using cloud9 IDE

Tags: node.js, express, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I am using a the cloud9 ide and getting an error as described in the title.
The file structure looks like this

```
client/
  views/
   -index.ejs
   routes/
    -index.js
-server.js
```

server.js file

```
var path = require('path');
var async = require('async');
var express = require('express');
var router = express();
var server = http.createServer(router);

router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')));


router.set('view engine','ejs');
//app.set('views','app/views');
router.locals.siteTitle = "Meetups";

//router.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
router.use(require('./client/routes/index'));
router.use(require('./client/routes/speaker'));
 server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function(){
  var addr = server.address();
  console.log("Chat server listening at", addr.address + ":" + addr.port);
});
```

While my index.js inside the routes folder which is receiving the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of     undefined router.get('/',function(req,res){

```
 var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
  router.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.render('index',{
    pageTitle:'Home',
    pageID:'home',
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your code to my c9 ide.

First issue in server.js you need to require http module.

```
var http = require("http");
```

And I have deleted this line because you didn't share this file.

```
router.use(require('./client/routes/speaker'));
```

It worked. At least, Node didn't throw any error.

Chat server listening at 0.0.0.0:8080

But I have some recommendations for you.

- First of all, in server.js please rename "router" variable to "app", because it's not a route module.
- For public folder, do not use client folder, create a folder named "public". Because you have routes, views, etc in client folder.
- For require expressions, try to make it at the top of the file.

> ```
> var routes = require('./client/routes');
>
> // some code ...
>
> app.use('/', routes);
> ```

- And import only one file for routes. Import other route files in routes/index.js
- I prefer createServer just before server.listen

> ```
> var server = http.createServer(app);
> server.listen(...)
> ```